# Copper/Aluminum Plate for Propane Burner

Tags: propane-burner, boil-equipment

I have a propane burner I recently purchased to do my boils.  It works great, however I  noticed some minor scorch marks in my stainless steel brew pot afterward.  I read somewhere that a copper or aluminum plate placed between the burner and the brew pot would help with this issue.  Any ideas where I can find such a plate?

**Update**

I was not able to find a copper or aluminum plate as other posters have suggested. However, I did find a Heat Diffuser at a local cooking supply store.  It's made of iron with a ceramic cover and measures 7 inches in diameter. Its made for simmering pasta sauces, but worked fine boiling wort. The scorch marks on my brew kettle were much smaller and easily removed after boiling a stout.  The draw back is the heat diffuser is meant for kitchen gas stoves, not outdoor propane burners.  When I vigorously stirred the pot, it would wobble a bit, but my pot never seemed to be in danger of tipping.

I have two issues with the heat diffuser. It has small rounded touch-points on the outside, and the diameter is only 7 inches, where as my brewpot is closer to 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try kitchen supply stores.  I bought a while ago at a Williams-Sonoma a disc that matched our cookware (and it was somewhat expensive), but I'm sure a lower-end cooking store would have a simple steel/copper/aluminum plate.  If your stove is gas, they work wonderfully in the kitchen as well!

Comment: I went to my local Williams-Sonoma and they were out of heat diffusers.  However they were able to point me in the right direction.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum is cheaper and easier to find, copper is a better conducter of heat.  So I would probably go with aluminum and I would look at the Home Depot or Loews.  They should have some sheets there.  Then I would cut it to size and throw my pot on it the next time I brewed.  Worst case, you can only find five inch wide strips, I would cut the strip into the desired length and then lay them side by side on the burner to form a plate.  Good luck man.  Happy hunting.